# Can't export stdcall method

Tags: rust, dllexport

I'm writing some code that use jni. My target platform is Windows. So my jni functions have to use stdcall calling convention but Rust exports functions only with cdecl calling convention.
I use MinGW(may be it important)

I wrote 2 functions:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn exported_cmethod(env: &JNIEnv, obj: jobject, path: jstring) {
    // Some jni staff
}
```

And

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "stdcall" fn exported_stdmethod(env: &JNIEnv, obj: jobject, path: jstring) {
    // Some jni staff
}
```

And than I used dumpbin to see exports table

```
dumpbin /exports acc_check.dll | findstr exported
2094  82D 000014A0 exported_cmethod = __ZN4core3fmt5Write10write_char17h774b1da469bdbfa3E
```

So as you can see Rust exported C method but didn't export stdcall method

What I do wrong?

Comment: Did you get a `.def` file with this when you compiled everything?

Comment: In my release folder I don't see any def files. May be it exists in any other folder I don't know.

Comment: The reason I was asking is because, depending on the compiler you'll use, you'll get mangling of function names under windows. There's a table of compatibility somewhere, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Actually, tell you what. Add `#[export_name="\x01_exported_stdmethod"]` before your definition and tell me if the symbol list changes

Comment: Yeah I did it before and it doesn't help. And as far as I know this workaround is about @ postfix.  
And I'm sorry but generating def file at link-time is more complicated than I thought. I can generate def file if it really necessary or I can give you full output of dumpbin.

Comment: the `.def` wasn't for me, it was because [most windows compilers mangle the method names for `stdcall` exports](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17806) ;-) I'm out of solutions for you if `export_name` didn't help, however. You're hitting an issue at the LLVM-rust boundary, basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to fix this issue.
I used gnu toolchain with MinGW and it was a mistake. I just downloaded MSVC toolchain with microsoft sdk and it solved my problem.